# IE8 on Windows 7 - Link To MSI causes about:blank to open as well

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-8

I'm maintaining an intranet page with installation instructions.

Annoyingly in Windows 7 / IE8 when I click on a link that contains an MSI the page jumps to about:blank - this didn't happen in XP! The href part is below, I tried target=_blank but no joy!.

`href="subffolder/amis.msi"`